# Problemas con ejercicio de Array

Tags: javascript

estoy aprendiendo en Javascript , y estoy atascado en este ejercicio , algun ayuda please??

> Crear un script en el que dados dos arrays de números, si ambos tienen la misma cantidad de elementos, mostrar un array que contenga la suma de cada elemento que se encuentre en la misma posición en los dos arrays. Ejemplo: [1,2,3] + [2,3,4] = [3,5,7]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Aqui no se realizan tareas escolares. Si quieres ayuda, necesitamos ver que es lo que has intentado, y que te está causando problemas.

Comment: ¿Has investigado? Muestra lo que has intentando y dónde te encuentras bloqueado...

Comment: La respuesta es sencilla, pero por favor muestra el código que has escrito hasta ahora para terminar de ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que podrías hacer. Recuerda que debes ser más explícito en lo que preguntas y que debes mostrar que al menos has hecho un esfuerzo en resolver el problema.

```js
let a = [2, 8, 8];
let b = [8, 9, 69];

function checkCorrectInput(someArray){
    // Este metodo comprueba que solo hay números en los arrays
    for(let i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){
        let test = parseFloat(someArray[i]);
        if(isNaN(test))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function sumArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo){
    let result = [];
    if(arrayOne.length == arrayTwo.length && (checkCorrectInput(arrayOne && checkCorrectInput(arrayTwo)))){
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
            let temp = parseFloat(arrayOne[i]) + parseFloat(arrayTwo[i]);
            result.push(temp);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

let example = sumArrays(a, b);

console.log(example);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda , espero ir mejorando poco a poco , intentaré realizar mejor las preguntas en las proximas consultas , saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arraysumar = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

for (let i = 0; i < arraysumar.length; i++){
}   
var arraysumar2 = new Array();
for (let i = 0; i < arraysumar.length; i++){
    arraysumar2[i] = arraysumar[i];
}   
// Suma de las dos array
var resultado = new Array ();
for (let i = 0; i < arraysumar.length; i++){
        resultado[i] = arraysumar[i] + arraysumar2[i];  
}   
console.log(resultado);
```